Tracking Android Channel IDs
I'm looking to use FCM for sending out push notifications and I'm curious if I should track on my end the channel IDs or if the phone itself will be handing that piece for me?
I'm not seeing anything regarding this, so I'm thinking the user's phone will keep track of this, but I feel like there's value in knowing which channel(s) the user wishes to receive notifications on.
If I am able to do this, how would I bubble this information up to my API?
